# Cannot implicitly convert 'byte[*,*]' to 'byte[*,*,*] '

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to acces the pixel data of my image. I want to know per pixel their BGR or HSV values. What values work best I have to figure out yet. Now I am stuck with accessing the pixel data.

First I try to convert my image to the right format. I read in the documentation that with the new Emgu I need to do that. Then I would like to acces the pixel data somehow so I can filter out the white pixels and look only at pixels that have a darker colour. Then I want to decide what the colour is of that darker colour and use that value to estimate a lower and upper threshold value for the Hue of another function. But that is all for later. First I need to be able to acces the pixel data properly and that goes wrong. This is new to me so I hope somebody can show my the mistake I make so I learn more!

Here is my code

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img = imgOriginal.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
Matrix<Byte> matrix = new Matrix<Byte>(imgOriginal.Rows, imgOriginal.Cols, imgOriginal.NumberOfChannels);
imgOriginal.CopyTo(matrix);

byte[,,] data = matrix.Data;

for (int i = matrix.Rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = matrix.Cols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        Byte B = data[i, j, 0];
        Byte G = data[i, j, 1];
        Byte R = data[i, j, 2];
    }
}
```

The error that I get is as following

```
Cannot implicitly convert 'byte[*,*]' to 'byte[*,*,*] '
```

If someone could help me out a little bit further that would be great!

**edit**

Here there is no error anymore. I don't see how I can acces my seperate data now though.

```
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img = imgOriginal.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
        Matrix<Byte> matrix = new Matrix<Byte>(imgOriginal.Rows, imgOriginal.Cols);
        imgOriginal.CopyTo(matrix);

        byte[,] data = matrix.Data;

        for (int i = matrix.Rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = matrix.Cols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                Byte B = data[i, j];
                Byte G = data[i, j];
                Byte R = data[i, j];
            }
        }
```

Comment: The message is pretty self-explaining: matrix.Data is a two-dimensional array and you are trying to treat it as if it was three-dimensional.

Comment: It should be `Matrix<Bgr>` If you want to access channels. But I don't know about the OpenCV `Matrix` well.

Comment: Okay, I thought 'byte[,,]' meant it was three-dimensional. I don't see how 'matrix.Data' is two-dimensional since I put in three values right?

Comment: Have you seen a 3D matrix lately?

Comment: I have changed `Matrix<Byte>` to `Matrix<Bgr>`. It still gives the same error. No extra errors. How else should I create my matrix?

Comment: @InBetween Oh yeah of course -_-. But how can I treat `matrix.Data` as it is two-dimensional then? I don't see where I can fix my problem

Comment: I have no idea what class `Matrix` is but the error is precisely telling you that `Matrix.Data` *is* a  two dimensional array. The problem is that *you* are trying to use it like a three dimensional array.

Comment: There might be easier ways to access that RGB data...

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/8eaaf685-939e-9365-2bd9-22ef02c39b20.htm) is a proper method I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have just downloaded and evaluated EmguCV sources from https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv .

The Data of Matrix is defined as

```
public TDepth[,] Data 
{
    get ...
    set ...
}
```

This basically means that you're trying to assign a two-dimensional value to a three-dimensional variable, that's why you get the error.

The only thing I could suggest to you for moving further is to read on EmguCV documentation to find out how to work with their data structures.

Comment: Okay thank you for that. I will look into that tomorrow since I need to go to class.. yay. I will get back on this tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

In the end all I needed to do was convert my `Mat` image to an `Image<,>` image.
Then I was able to access the pixels seperately and give them for example another value. The information to do this was here. http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images

Here is the code

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img = imgTest.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();

for (int i = img.Rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = img.Cols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (img.Data[i, j, 0] <= 100)
        {
            img.Data[i, j, 0] = 255;
        }
    }
}
```